# Nonexistence of metric space on $\mathbb{R}$ in which only $\emptyset$ and $\mathbb{R}$ are open.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I'm trying to work through Analysis 2 script and prove a statement I came across.

There exists no metric $(\mathbb{R}, d)$ in which only $\mathbb{R}$ and $\emptyset$ are open sets. (the script is in German. So these are not the exact words.)

I think the main idea is that such a metric in cases of uncountable subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ would lead to contradiction. But I'm not sure if it's correct. It would be great if someone can take a look at it in case I'm terribly off the track.

**Proof**

Assume that such a metric, let it be $d'$ do exist. Further Let $ A := \{x \in \mathbb{R} | a < x < b\} $

It follows that A is not open, which means there exists a point $\tilde{x}$ in A that is not an inner point:

$$\forall \epsilon > 0, U_\epsilon(\tilde{x}) \cap (\mathbb{R} \setminus A) \neq \emptyset$$

let $\epsilon_{1} \leq min\{d'(\tilde{x},a), d'(\tilde{x},b)\}$, then

$$U_{\epsilon_{1}}(\tilde{x}) \cap (\mathbb{R} \setminus A) \neq \emptyset$$

let $y \in U_{\epsilon_{1}}(\tilde{x}) \cap (\mathbb{R} \setminus A)$.

It follows that
$$d'(y,\tilde{x}) \leq \epsilon_{1} $$

which is a contradition to $y \notin A$, which means $d'(y,\tilde{x}) \geq max\{d'(\tilde{x},a), d'(\tilde{x},b) $

The assumption is false. And such a metric does not exist.

$\square$

and another question, could we also argue with the completeness of  $\mathbb{R}\$ instead?

many thanks!

Comment: Metric spaces are Hausdorff spaces. If such a metric existed, there would be no way to find two disjoint open sets, containing respectively two given real numbers $x\neq y$.

Comment: See [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33930/showing-that-a-set-x-with-a-trivial-topology-is-not-metrizable).  Countability does not enter into it (though you do need the set to have at least two elements, of course).

Comment: @Adren thanks for the response! we havent learned about Hausdorff yet. But once given Metric spaces are Hausdorff spaces, and the definition of Hausdorff spaces, I can understand your explanation.

Comment: @lulu I thought all countable subsets would indeed not be open since they would  contain irrational numbers in the neighbourhood, thats why I brought up uncountable sets. I feel like I'm missing some basic definitions.

Comment: Suppose you had two different points $a,b$. Let $r=d(a,b)$.  We know $r>0$ from the axioms.  Then the ball of radius $\frac r2$ about $a$ is open, by definition, and it is not empty (since $a$ is in it) and it is not the whole set since $b$ is not in it.

Comment: @lulu I see it now! I think I now understand the axioms better. Thank you :D

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Showing that a set X with a trivial topology is not metrizable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33930/showing-that-a-set-x-with-a-trivial-topology-is-not-metrizable)

Comment: @OliverDíaz thanks there, lulu also linked to this post in his/her comment. The post helped a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply say that, if $r=d(0,1)$, then the set $B_r(0)$ is an open set (since it is an open ball, which is neither empty (since $0\in B_r(0)$) nor $\Bbb R$ (since $1\notin B_r(0)$).

Concerning your proof, I don't see why we should have $U_{\epsilon_{1}}(\tilde{x}) \cap (\mathbb{R} \setminus A) \neq \emptyset$.

And no, we cannot use “since $\Bbb R$ is complete” since it is *not* being assumed that $\Bbb R$ is complete with respect to the metric $d$.

Comment: I went back and looked at the proof for every epsilon-neighbourhood is open and realized that it entirely follows from the axioms of metric spaces. So now I understand what you are saying. Thank you for helping me to learn. :D