# If a metric space $M$ has only countably many open sets, prove that $M$ is countable

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, metric-spaces

I found the following exercise

If a metric space $M$ has only countably many open sets, prove that $M$ is
countable.

in Kaplansky's Set theory and metric spaces (section 4.3, exercise 19)

I was wondering if I take $\Bbb R$ with the trivial topology $\{\Bbb R, \emptyset\}$. Isn't this a counterexample? $\Bbb R$ has countably many (2) open sets, but it certainly isn't countable. What I am doing wrong? And how do I solve that exercise?

Comment: The trivial topology over $\mathbb R$ is not metrizable.

Comment: @Justauser Why isn't it just the good old euclidean metric?

Comment: @some_math_guy because the topology induced by the euclidean metric has a lot of open sets that are neither $\Bbb R$ nor $\varnothing$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/33930/42969

Comment: The trivial topology is generated by the **semi-** or **pseudo**-metric $d(x,y)=0$ for all $x,y$. For a (proper) metric, singletons are closed and hence the complements $X\setminus\{x\}$ with $x\in X$ are distinct open sets.

Answer (score 2):

> I was wondering if I take $\Bbb R$ with the trivial topology $\{\Bbb R, \emptyset\}$. Isn't this a counterexample?

No, because that is not a metrizable topology.

> $\Bbb R$ has countably many (2) open sets, but it certainly isn't countable.

As in $\Bbb R$ with Euclidean topology? The number of open subsets of the euclidean $\Bbb R$ is uncountable: the "$(x-1,x+1)$" formula produces uncountable number of distinct open subsets.

> And how do I solve that exercise?

Let $X$ be a metric space and $\tau$ its collection of open subsets. Then $X\to \tau$ given by $x\mapsto X\backslash \{x\}$ is well defined and injective. Thus $X$ is countable if $\tau$ is.

Comment: I'm way late to the party on this one but I'm not sure how this argument works.  Just because a family of sets is countable, that does not imply the set of all intersections (or even of all nested countable intersections) of sets in that family is countable.  For example, in $\mathbb R$, the intervals of the form $(p,q)$ with $p,q\in\mathbb Q$ forms a countable family of intervals, and yet every $x\in \mathbb R$ is a member of some nested intersection of such intervals.

Comment: In fact, I believe the cantor set can be given an equivalent metric where there are only countably many open balls. Just let $d(x,y)=\frac{1}{2^n}$, where $n$ is the index of the first ternary digit that distinguishes $x$ from $y$.  Then there are only finitely many balls of a given radius, and in fact $B(x,r)=B(x,s)$ whenever $2^{-k}<r<s\leq 2^{-k+1}$.  So there are countably many balls.  We therefore need to consider a wider range of open sets then just balls.

Comment: @MW maybe you're right. I'm not exactly sure. Either way, I fixed the answer with the same argument as Carlyle uses.

Answer (score 2):

Some of the other issues in your question have been addressed already, but here is another way to prove the result:

Note that in any metric space $X$ and for any $x\in X$, the singleton $\{x\}$ is always closed. Thus its complement is always open. If there were uncountably many $x\in X$ then we immediately have uncountably many open sets, those in the set

$$S = \{X\setminus \{x\}\subset X|x\in X\}$$

Which proves the contrapositive

Comment: One can avoid using an argument by contradiction by looking at the map $x\in X \mapsto X\setminus\{x\} \in \tau_X$, which is injective ($\tau_X$ is the topology).

Comment: @Didier Thank you, the injectivity of the map you mention is certainly required to formally prove that $S$ is uncountable, but I realise now that this argument can be rephrased as a proof of the contrapositive, I have made an edit regarding this.